# Tags: humans, health

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I just put in a tag wiki edit request for [humans](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans) because the current questions are all human physiology. I then saw a question tagged [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) that is also about human physiology.

I am wondering which tag to use for questions specifically relating to the physical capabilities of humans in space.

Comment: [human-physiology] doesn't exist right now, and I'd rather not set up a pre-emptive synonym. Make another meta post if/when it becomes an issue. I also hesitate to link the two tags just because the current questions in [humans] are all about physiology.

Answer (score 5):

I would propose that we use the [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) tag or [human-physiology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-physiology) for these questions.

[human](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human) could be applied to the activities of humans in space, but we already have [manned-flight](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manned-flight) so I don't think it's a useful tag at the moment, unless we are talking about human colonization of space (but all the questions I can think of would fit under [human-physiology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-physiology)).

Comment: Manned-flight is a better one than humans, I agree.

Comment: I agree, "human" as a tag sounds way too broad

Answer (score 0):

There is a term and scientific discipline called [space-medicine](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-medicine). In my eyes, this makes sense for most humans-in-space-related questions. [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) does not fit completely. I could imagine events in space (observed by exploration activities) that have an influence on the health of people here on Earth, too. So for phenomena on human bodies in space, it is too wide. [human-physiology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-physiology) is also nice, but I think that this is useful for rather specific questions.